# jQuery AJAX Not POSTing Full Array to Server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, multidimensional-array

I have a farily large multidimensional Javascript array which I'm passing to my PHP file with an AJAX POST as such:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "forms/scripts/testArray.php",
    data: {
        header: header,
        gridData: gridData
    }
});
```

`gridData` is my multidimensional array which has 1000 elements with each of their child arrays containing 3 elements. When I debug and look at the data in my PHP file, there are only about 350 elements from the array that arrived from the `POST`.

Using Firebug, I get this info about File Size Sent and File Size Received:

[image: POST Problem]

As you can see, the little pop-up is telling me the AJAX call sent 462.8 KB but only 4.9 KB was actually received. Is this true? Is that why I'm only getting part of the array I'm attempting to POST?

Also, is this the best way to move a multidimensional array from Javascript to PHP via an AJAX POST?

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Total received is the response not the post. Something else is affecting what you're getting

Comment: There is no multidimensional array in JavaScript, arrays are zero-based. Try checking your array before sending to server.

Comment: The array is fine. I'm receiving it fine in PHP, I'm just not receiving the entire array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, something in the toolchain is limiting the maximum amount of stuff that can be sent/received. This can either by in your webserver (Apache probably), or (more likely) in your PHP settings. PHP has some settings like post_max_size, max_input_time, max_input_nesting_level, max_input_vars, etcetera. You should check out these settings!

Comment: Thanks - Here are my settings: `post_max_size = 500M`  |  `max_input_nesting_level = 64`  |  `max_input_time = 60`. It doesn't seem like `500M` would prevent this POST, would it?

Comment: After further examination, I needed to set `max_input_vars = (large #)`. In my case, I set it to `max_input_vars = 1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a weird character in the data throwing off the json encoding/decoding on or just after the last element that is being 'received'.

Comment: To test this, I created an array of 10,000 elements with each element containing the text `apples and oranges` and it still cuts off the array in my PHP file to about 1,000 elements from the 10,000 the array originally had in Javascript. So after doing this test, I don't think a strange character is throwing me off...

Answer (score -1):

Remove `;`(semicolon) in `php.ini` file, set increase `max_input_vars` then it works:

`max_input_vars = 10000`